# Do i need a comma or a semicolon in, "..., such as inaudible tags for indiscernible dialogue."?

Tags: commas, semicolons

Otherwise, use appropriate notation tags, such as **inaudible tags for indiscernible dialogue**.

Comment: Can you edit this to expand on what your question is? At the moment your title and question seem identical, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere you are willing to put a semicolon, you should also be willing to put a full stop;  semicolons join two sentences and indicate to the reader that they are linked in some way.

The semicolon in the previous sentence hints that the second sentence gives the reason for the first, but it would have been correct (and normal) to put a full stop there.

So perhaps you can answer the question yourself:  Would you write:

> Otherwise, use appropriate notation tags. Such as inaudible tags for indiscernible dialogue.

If you wouldn't write that, then you also should not write a semicolon. The second part doesn't have verb and isn't a formal sentence, so it is incorrect.

Generally, the semicolon is an optional feature of English; we can get rid of it completely without losing anything vital.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of whether you need a comma (since a semicolon is out of the question, as explained by James), my preference would be to remove it, but its presence isn't irregular.